# How to Display an Image From a Database in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-blade, avatar

I have an admin template that I registered into an app from a purchase. The template is very well set up, and parts of it are written in Laravel. I'm able to register new users in my modification, but the user profile image is having problems. When a newly registered user is enacted, the file name is stored in the respective database. However, the image is not able to be displayed. I can even see the image name in the Google Chrome web tools when inspecting the app code. This image is being saved, it's just not displaying on the webpage (at least not on the sidebar).

```
@if (auth()->user()->profile->pic == null)
    <img src="{{asset('storage/uploads/users/no_avatar.jpg')}}" alt="user-img" class="img-circle">
@else
    <img src="{{ auth()->user()->profile->pic }}" alt="user-img" class="img-circle">
@endif
```

If there is something that I'm doing wrong, it must be a basic Laravel issue. I don't know how, but the image must be able to be taken from the database and shown in the view that I pull up or navigate to. If someone could tell me how to properly include the profile pic on the frontend view like any other Laravel app, it would help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you storing in `pic`? Is the image stored in the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your storage path you can use `storage_path` helper function instead of `asset` so your code should be:

```
storage_path('uploads/users/no_avatar.jpg');
```

and for the user that has uploaded picture, if you store the relative path to the picture stored in the public folder then you can use

```
{{ url(auth()->user()->profile->pic) }}
```

if the value of `auth()->user()->profile->pic` is `img/profile.jpg` then you should have `img` folder containing `profile.jpg` within your project `public` directory.

Comment: Okay, but what if the data I want is only within a separate database connected to the laravel app? Couldn't it be obtained like the user's name?

Comment: I thought there was a way for the app to display info from a database interaction. It just doesn't seem right to store all users in the storage or public directories.

Comment: the picture has to exists physically on some server in order for you to display it. I don't get your point of the app being able to display info from a database interaction. You can use Amazon S3 service or similar in order to keep the pictures somewhere, but they have to exist. And what you keep in the DB is usually a path to the image, not the image itself.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not sure how to select the image. If the path is what is stored in the database, how do I put that exact path in the database?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads

so from here you store the `$path` to the database.

Comment: I'm aware of laravel's filesystem package. What I'm asking is which path should I use? If I use the $request->file type of path configuration, it only goes back as far as the database table within the name of the link. Is there a helper function in laravel that can represent or construct an images proper path to a database? What should the format of the image path look like?

Comment: The main point to understand is that there is no path to database, the database is a separate filesystem. It can be on a different server as well, it won't open a directory for you to access within the database. The main point is that you store the image on a disk, either local or remote disk such as Amazon S3. Local means the disk on the server, and in the database you store a path where the image is located on the disk, not where is located in the database. So if you store your images in local disk, the path will be `/images/image.jpg` or similar.